Что делают в коде %v и \n?
У нас есть программа по угадыванию числа.
Не понимаю что в ней выполняют символы %v и \n.
func main() {

    var number = 43

    for {
        var n = rand.Intn(100) + 1
        if n < number {
            fmt.Printf("%v слишком маленькое число.\n", n)
        } else if n > number {
            fmt.Printf("%v слишком большое число.\n", n)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("угадал! %v\n", n)
            break
    

Как понимаю %v проверяет число в переменной(имею ввиду область видимости for), в нашем случае число которое появилось рандомно.
Какой синтаксис несет \n инфо к моменту написания вопроса не нашел.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

%v это универсальный спецификатор, выводит объекты любого типа . \n знак конца строки. Если его не поставить в Printf, то следующая функция вывода напечатает на той же строке

Быстрый поиск в гугеле https://golang-blog.blogspot.com/2020/03/fmt-printf-usage.html

Просто и качественно описано тут: https://www.w3schools.com/go/go_formatting_verbs.php

%v - Нужен для того чтобы в самом тексте писать значение любого типа, это удобно когда нужно вставлять в текст значения переменных. Вот пример, выводят одно и то же, но первая функция более читаемая и удобная в написании.
var number = 43
var s = "string"
fmt.Printf("Какой-то текст число: %v, какой-то текст строка: %v\n",number, s)
fmt.Print("Какой-то текст число: ", number," какой-то текст строка:", s,"\n")

\n - Переход на новую строку, запуском следующей команды можно убедиться в этом:
fmt.Printf("Новая строка \nНовая строка \nНовая строка \nНовая строка ")

